# JSoup - remove tags with particular word in them (and everything within the tags)

Tags: html, jsoup

I have a webpage that has html tags of the form

```
<section class="feature-authorized-retailer pdp-outofstock-js hide">
    <div class="retailer-notification">
        <span>This product is out of stock</span>
    </div>

            <section id="marketing-product-actions" class="product-content-form-marketing-product-actions product-actions">
                <div class="product-content-form-product-actions-primary product-actions-primary">
                    <a class="product-content-form-out-of-stock button secondary">Out of Stock</a>
                </div>
            </section>

</section>
```

As you can see in the outer "section" tag it has the word "hide" in the class name.  Is there a way to identify tags like these with the word "hide" in the class name using JSoup such that I could remove them and all html within these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To select elements using Jsoup you can use most [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

1. Select all elements with class `hide`:

```
document.select(".hide")
```

Element may contain many classes but this will match if one of them equals `hide`.

It will match `class="abc hide abc"` but won't match `class="abc abchideabc abc"`.

2. Select all elements where value of attribute `class` contains string `hide`;

```
document.select("[class~=hide]")
```

This one will match `class="abc hide abc"` but it will also match `class="abc abchideabc abc"`

To remove selected elements use `document.select(...).remove()`

Comment: hmmmm for some reason ```document.select(".hide")``` and ```document.select(".hide").remove()``` are returning identical results for me.  It doesn't look like ```remove()``` is actually removing them

Comment: Looks like ```html.select("*").removeClass(".hide");``` did the trick though